# To create an executable from QT for linux

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, centos, executable

I am trying to develop a GUI for one of the requirements for daily activities at my  workplace. I am using QT creator for it. The problem is that all my team members have Centos machines whereas I have developed in ubuntu system. In QT I am using python coding for the development of code. How do I share it as an executable and make it work on their respective platforms?

Comment: Have you tried?  Centos is still Linux, I would be surprised if executable created on one do not run on the other.  It might just need to install some prerequisites on Centos (ex. libraries if they are not statically linked).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question is how do i generate an executable from QT that is platform independent.

Comment: Well CentOS and Ubuntu *are* the same platform IMHO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get the most out of this site.

Comment: `ldd yourExecutable` then package all needed libraries with the executable and put them in destination host. if you want more professional way, take a look how to create an rpm or deb package

Comment: Since you are using python, http://www.pyinstaller.org/ might be useful. But I would recommend you simply tar up the python files and distribute that